# Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object' , but it's already an array

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have method to get data from back end to array

Here is method

```
getUtilities(): void {
    // DropdownHelpers.fillDropdownOptions(
    //     this._propertyService.getMarketingInformationUtilityTypes(),
    //     this.utilities
    // );
    this._propertyService.getMarketingInformationUtilityTypes().subscribe(result => {
        this.utilities = result.items;
        console.log(this.utilities);
    });
}
```

and here  is what I see in the console

[image]

But when I try to do `*ngFor="let utility of utilities"`

I got

> MarketingEditComponent.html:38 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Where is my problem? Data is returning to array

Comment: `this.utilities` maybe undefined before the API call - at that time it's not an array. Add `*ngIf` before the loop to check if it is an array OR initialize it to an empty array when you define it.

Comment: the initial value is an empty array `utilities: any[] = [];` @David

Comment: The `console.log` comes from `edit-property-market..ion.component.ts`, but the error message comes from `MarketingEditComponent.html`. Can you post your HTML and TS for `MarketingEditComponent`.

Comment: it's same component @KurtHamilton

Comment: @EugeneSukh So... can you post it?

Answer (score 1):

`this.utilities` maybe undefined before the API call - at that time it's not an array.

Solutions:

- Add `*ngIf` before the loop to check if it is an array in the template.

OR

- Initialize it to an empty array when you define it i.e
  `this.utilities = [];`

Comment: `utilities` is loading at `ngOnInit()`, I call `ngFor` at the modal show. So it can be null.

Maybe the problem in data structure?

Comment: `utilities: any[] = [];` at start of TS file

Comment: Or like this `utilities: SelectItem[] = [];`

Comment: Is is getting redefined somewhere else in your component? Can you share the relevant snippets from the template as well?

Answer (score 0):

when you define utilities declare it as

> utilities: any; or utilities:any = [];

and in your use *ngIf before you iterate something like

```
<div *ngIf="utilities"> 
<div *ngFor="let util of utilities">
{{util.OptionDto.name}} {{util.OptionDto.id}} 
</div>
</div>
```

Nothing new from what they've said earlier. If your still confused provide me a stackblitz.